# Cross-platform C++: Use the native string encoding or standardise across platforms?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, unicode, cross-platform

We are specifically eyeing Windows and Linux development, and have come up with two differing approaches that both seem to have their merits.  The natural unicode string type in Windows is UTF-16, and UTF-8 in linux.

We can't decide whether the best approach:

1. Standardise on one of the two in all our application logic (and persistent data), and make the other platforms do the appropriate conversions
2. Use the natural format for the OS for application logic (and thus making calls into the OS), and convert only at the point of IPC and persistence.

To me they seem like they are both about as good as each other.

Comment: What's should we choose and why? Not obvious?

Comment: "What" not "what's". Damn phone

Comment: Some cross-platform libraries (e.g. Qt) may make their own choice. If you use them, follow their ideas (e.g. QString and QChar when using Qt).

Comment: @Basile - what if the third party libraries that you want to use on different platforms are at odds with each other??  Eg, using Win32 controls on Windows and GTK+ on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and UTF-8 in linux.

It's mostly true for modern Linux. Actually encoding depends on what API or library is used. Some hardcoded to use UTF-8. But some read LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE or LANG environment variables to detect encoding to use (like Qt library). So be careful.

> We can't decide whether the best approach

As usual it depends.

If 90% of code is to deal with platform specific API in platform specific way, obviously it is better to use platform specific strings. As an example - a device driver or native iOS application.

If 90% of code is complex business logic that is shared across platforms, obviously it is better to use same encoding on all platforms. As an example - chat client or browser.

In second case you have a choice:

- Use cross platform library that provides strings support (Qt, ICU, for example)
- Use bare pointers (I consider std::string a "bare pointer" too)

If working with strings is a significant part of your application, choosing a nice library for strings is a good move. For example Qt has a very solid set of classes that covers 99% of common tasks. Unfortunately, I has no ICU experience, but it also looks very nice.

When using some library for strings you need to care about encoding only when working with external libraries, platform API or sending strings over the net (or disk). For example, a lot of Cocoa, C# or Qt (all has solid strings support) programmers know very little about encoding details (and it is good, since they can focus on their main task).

My experience in working with strings is a *little* specific, so I personally prefer bare pointers. Code that use them is very portable (in sense it can be easily reused in other projects and platforms) because has less external dependencies. It is extremely simple and fast also (but one probably need some experience and Unicode background to feel that).

I agree that bare pointers approach is not for everyone. It is good when:

- You work with entire strings and splitting, searching, comparing is a rare task
- You can use same encoding in all components and need a conversion only when using platform API
- All your supported platforms has API to:

  - Convert from your encoding to that is used in API
  - Convert from API encoding to that is used in your code
- Pointers is not a problem in your team

From my a *little* specific experience it is actually a very common case.

When working with bare pointers it is good to choose encoding that will be used in entire project (or in all projects).

From my point of view, UTF-8 is an ultimate winner. If you can't use UTF-8 - use strings library or platform API for strings - it will save you a lot of time.

Advantages of UTF-8:

- Fully ASCII compatible. Any ASCII string is a valid UTF-8 string.
- C std library works great with UTF-8 strings. (*)
- C++ std library works great with UTF-8 (std::string and friends). (*)
- Legacy code works great with UTF-8.
- Quite any platform supports UTF-8.
- Debugging is MUCH easier with UTF-8 (since it is ASCII compatible).
- No Little-Endian/Big-Endian mess.
- You will not catch a classical bug "Oh, UTF-16 is not always 2 bytes?".

(*) Until you need to lexical compare them, transform case (toUpper/toLower), change normalization form or something like this - if you do - use strings library or platform API.

Disadvantage is questionable:

- Less compact for Chinese (and other symbols with large code point numbers) than UTF-16.
- Harder (a little actually) to iterate over symbols.

So, I recommend to use UTF-8 as common encoding for project(s) that doesn't use any strings library.

But encoding is not the only question you need to answer.

There is such thing as [normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). To put it simple, some letters can be represented in several ways - like one glyph or like a combination of different glyphs. The common problem with this is that most of string compare functions treat them as different symbols. If you working on cross-platform project, choosing one of normalization forms as standard is a right move. This will save your time.

For example if user password contains "йёжиг" it will be differently represented (in both UTF-8 and UTF-16) when entered on Mac (that mostly use Normalization Form D) and on Windows (that mostly likes Normalization Form C). So if user registered under Windows with such password it will a problem for him to login under Mac.

In addition I would not recommend to use wchar_t (or use it only in windows code as a UCS-2/UTF-16 char type). The problem with wchar_t is that there is no encoding associated with it. It's just an abstract wide char that is larger than normal char (16 bits on Windows, 32 bits on most *nix).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the same encoding internally, and normalize the data at entry point. This will involve less code, less gotchas, and will allow you to use the same cross platform library for string processing.

I'd use unicode (utf-16) because it's simpler to handle internally and should perform better because of the constant length for each character. UTF-8 is ideal for output and storage because it's backwards compliant with latin ascii, and unly uses 8 bits for English characters. But inside the program 16-bit is simpler to handle.

Comment: Are you suggesting using utf-8 for storage? Seems like the worst of both worlds.

Comment: What is worst with utf8? It is very clear defined. It is very compact (for non-chinese languages). It is very in use.

Comment: Nothing is worst with utf-8. Worst is with utf-8 for storage and utf-16 in memory on linux

Comment: UTF-16 does not have a constant length for each character. It is a variable length encoding. Perhaps you are thinking of UTF-32, the only standard constant length Unicode encoding.

Comment: And as I learned today, an Abstract Unicode Character may actually be comprised of multiple code points, so if you deal with Abstract Unicode Characters then UTF-32 is still variable length!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: He's probably thinking of UCS2, the 16-bit encoding at the basis of Microsoft's wchar_t. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I think you've got that wrong. UTF-16 uses 16 bit character points, just that some code points require multiple character points. It being a variable length encoding. Just as UTF-8 uses 8 bit character units.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am aware of that. UCS2, on the other hand, did only have a fixed-width 16bit encoding - which is why Microsoft chose it for its wchar_t - but which proved insufficient as the number of Unicode characters grew.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you *have* a 16-bit wchar_t. Since MS and Linux disagree on its width, that makes it pretty much useless for cross-platform coding, no?

Comment: @DevSolar that's correct but it's not what you said earlier. In fact utf8 is the best choice for cross platform. But nobody said that.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 provides the new string types `u16string` and `u32string`. Depending on the support your compiler versions deliver, and the expected life expectancy, it might be an idea to stay forward-compatible to those.

Other than that, using the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library is probably your best shot at cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite enlightening on the topic. http://www.utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score -1):

Programming with UTF-8 is difficult as lengths and offsets are mixed up.  e.g.

```
    std::string s = Something();
    std::cout << s.substr(0, 4);
```

does not necessarily find the first 4 chars.

I would use whatever a `wchar_t` is.  On Windows that will be UTF-16.  On some *nix platforms it might be UTF-32.

When saving to a file, I would recommend converting to UTF-8.  That often makes the file smaller, and removes any platform dependencies due to differences in `sizeof(wchar_t)` or to byte order.

Comment: UTF-16 has the same issue.  You just won't notice with Western characters.

Comment: That's true, but Windows has no support for UTF-32.  Most of the utf-16 chars from > 0xFFFF are historical character sets e.g. Ancient Greek and Cuneiform, but there are a few that might be important.  e.g. HAN CJK extensions.  The developer needs to decide if that is important.  If it is, then the solution gets more complex.

Comment: True.  I'd forgotten that Kanji fit in 16 bits.

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this please explain what is wrong?  Thanks.