# Is it wise to use implicit conversion to a char array, or write explicit conversion methods?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'm writing a string class for UTF-8 strings, and i'm encountering a design problem.

I would like some of my methods to take both a `const char *` and a `const Utf8String &` as input values. This is in order to avoid computing the length and validating the UTF-8 string when a user passes a `Utf8String`, and to avoid a useless memory allocation for a temporary `Utf8String` when a user passes a `const char *`.

I also want to overload the `const char *` operator (equivalent to `string::c_str()`) because it's handy. The problem is that it creates an ambuiguity.

Is this why the STL strings provide a `c_str()` method instead of overloading operator `const char *`?

And what can I do here? Keep the overloaded operator `const char *` and only one of the two possible signatures for my methods (either `const char *` or `const Utf8String &`), or remove the `const char *` operator overload and keep the two possible method signatures?

Comment: Can you give pseudocode of the function signatures you want so we can understand your problem better?
Can you clarify what exactly is your question?

Comment: You have to break implicit conversions: Either make the constructors explicit or make the conversion operator explicit (C++11), or use something like 'c_str'.

Comment: That should not be the source of ambiguity. See http://ideone.com/DrO7jX. There must be more to your code that is causing the ambiguity. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to write two methods instead of using the `(const char*)` operator. It could lead to various problems.

The question is, how is the memory managed of the returned pointer?

One could write fatal code like this:

```
const char* getText() {
    YourType x = "text";
    return x;
}
```

Here, your type is destructed, and most likely your char array as well. But this compiles fine and also looks well. Hard to spot the problem in your code.

Using a dedicated method is allowing you to make the use clear:

```
class YourType {
public:
    const char* createCharArray() const;
    const char* accessCharArray() const;
}
```

One method will allocate a new char array, while the other will just create an internal temporary char representation which is destroyed with the type itself.

Another issue is using a constructor like this:

```
class YourType {
public:
    YourType(const char *str);
}
```

It is not actually clear what this constructor does. Is your class storing the pointer to the string, or does your class create an internal copy of the string. This will most likely lead to code which can be hard to understand.

```
void printText(const YourType &text) {
}
```

Allows this:

```
printText("Text");
```

But also works for this:

```
void foo(const char* text) {
    char *str = new char[strlen(text)+1];
    std::strcpy(str, text);
    printText(str);
}
```

Here I suggest to use a `static` conversion method instead:

```
class YourType {
public:
    static YourType fromCharArray(const char *str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own string class is a lot of fun (and a good exercise). But what I found out is that standard `std::string` works for UTF-8 strings extremely well.

Before I go completely off topic, my answer to your questions is: when in doubt, mimic standard things (i.e. `std::string`). At least two reasons why to do that. **First**, those interfaces a usually well designed (since many people with different background were working on them). **Second**, developers usually already know how to use those things correctly.

But back to UTF-8 strings. I don't know why you need a **separate class** for UTF-8 strings and how much time you spent thinking whether you really need it (I'm curios to know you reasons). The thing is that UTF-8 is part of Unicode standard which is not that simple. And if you want a full featured UTF-8 string you will end up implementing a decent part of unicode standard (like normalization forms, weird capitalization rules (did you know that in Greek language letter [Sigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma) has different capitalization rules when it's in the end of the word?), etc.). I'm sure you don't want to do that, because if you need that, it's probably better to use ICU, Qt or some other library with decent Unicode support.

So, if what you need is just a storage for Utf-8 characters with some `utf8_to_encoding()`, `utf8_from_encoding()`, `utf8_next_code_point()` I recommend to stick to `std::string` and provide other features you need as a free functions. For example:

```
std::string utf8_from_utf16(const uint16_t *s, size_t len);
```

Maybe my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114971/506566) on the similar topic could be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes std::string can store UTF-8 text, but when i want to take a N "char" long substring starting at the M-th "char", i don't want std::string::substring to cut into the middle of a UTF-8 encoded code point. Instead i want it to return a N code points long substring starting at the N-th code point. My class is doing that code point / byte abstraction by expecting code piont poisitons/lengths instead of byte position/lengths. Same thing applies to other functions.

Comment: And it's also a good oocasion to add some features such as ToInt(), ToReal(), Trim(), Split(), and that kind of features that would have been handy to have in std::string, even if it can be done otherwise. I also need conversions from this Utf8String class to another Ucs2String class, both having conversion constructors taking an instance of the other class as input. I don't need a perfect 100% complete handling of unicode, so i'm not going to use something like ICU.

Comment: Be careful then. Even substring() is not that easy as it seams to be. For example Russian letter "ё" could be both represented as code point 0451  or as a sequence of 0435 0308. And correct implementations are required to handle both equally. But for naive substring() implementation it will be possible to break 0435 0308 sequence. See http://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization for more examples. Because of such complexity it's better just to use std::string and don't pretend that you have a unicode support (which in 80% case you don't actually need).

Comment: Point is, that if you need search / split by only ASCII characters (like "/" to work with file path or " " to split words or "." to split sentences) you can use anything that works witch `char` (strstr(), strchr(), etc.). But if you want to really work with text (like smart search, building a document word index), then it's better to use something that implements unicode correctly and fully.

Comment: Mmm good point. I'm using the library UTF-8 cpp to handle UTF-8, i am not doing it myself.

Comment: Actually, utf8cpp is a great example. It provides a set of UTF-8 functions on top of existing containers (like `std::string`). That's exactly what I was talking about. But you need to keep in mind that this library only provides UTF-8 support - which is a way to encode unicode code points into bytes. It still will not help to implement substring() or char_at() correctly ("ё" example). Because it doesn't know anything about Unicode except of how to encode and decode code points.